# My Hosts file broke: Ping request could not find host test

Tags: windows-xp, ping, hosts-file

Here's my hosts(with a single entry):

```
127.0.0.1 test
```

But it's not working any more:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>ping test
Ping request could not find host test. Please check the name and try again.
```

Why?

**UPDATE**

It stops working ever since I used **[openvpn](http://openvpn.net/)**

**UPDATE2**

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the original one is encoded as something other than plain-text. Try renaming the file and creating a new plain-text file.

Answer (score 1):

Your host file NEEDS  the first entry to be 127.0.0.1 localhost to properly function, according to Microsoft. That may be an issue as well. Add that in then reboot and try

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be the *first* entry, and Windows 7 doesn't even put `localhost` to the hosts file.

Comment: You're right that it doesn't need to be the first entry, my mistake. However, EVERY Windows 7 installation has it in there that I've seen

Comment: They are commented-out, however, and ignored by the resolver.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem trying to ping a machine across our VPN

I made *two* identical entries, each on a separate line, and that made it work

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem none of presented suggestions worked for me. I found the clue there:
https://serverfault.com/a/50950/161292

I rigth-clicked on hosts file and went to Properties->Security->Advanced. then I checked *Inherit from Parent* and clicked 'apply'. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have a strange problem! But here are some ideas.

a)make sure you're opening the right file
notepad C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

b)Check that the file path is right here at this registry key. Check that the path there is   The actual HOSTS file location 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\DataBasePath

check that DataBasePath has value %SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc

c)you could also try running hijackthis. See if it lists something with key o1, that's  host file redirection..  or something to do with it. you could then check the box and choose "fix checked"

You could give it up and do a system restore, which is likely to fix it if you can go back to a good time but it won't tell you what was wrong.. maybe some people will have some other ideas.

Comment: I've uploaded a snapshot of the register entries,and the value of `DataBasePath` is OK...

Comment: here's a long-shot, in internet explorer tools options connections, is proxy server unchecked? that is a general windows setting 'cos it affects chrome too. But it doesn't affect ping.. and probably wouldn't affect hosts either.. though i've heard of people using proxies for dns.. but worth a look.

Comment: this answer http://superuser.com/questions/86751/possible-reasons-windows-system32-drivers-etc-hosts-is-not-working-appart-from-t  suggests some things, like sfc /scannow  But it looks like the guy mainly just did an install of service packs and updates. So, I reckon a repair installation would have fixed it for him. Similarly, a system restore. But you may want to hang about and see if anybody has an interesting idea!

Comment: @barlop: It certainly doesn't affect lower level tools such as `ping`.

Comment: @gravvity as I thought then!

Comment: @fms "How do I reset the hosts file back to the default?"  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972034   <-- that's worth a try it's mentioned by one person there as something that worked for them

Answer (score 0):

If you just edited your host file, you maybe need to flush your dns table

ipconfig -flushdns

ping test

Comment: I think it might be ipconfig /flushdns.  At least it is on XP.

Comment: I just tried ,still not working..

Answer (score 0):

Check the advaced settings of your TCP/IP settings, make sure the LMHOSTS option is **enabled**.

[image]

Comment: `LMHOSTS` is a separate file from `HOSTS`, and only used for NetBIOS lookups.

Comment: @grawity: That's true, but I've experienced that this setting applies to both files.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is overstating the obvious; The hosts file resides in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc if you have edited this file in a text editor ensure that it hasnt added an extension, as far as windows is concerned the file must have no extension
ie hosts.
not hosts.txt

Comment: You could also try:   netsh interface ipv4 reset    ipconfig /flushdns    ipconfig /registerdns